# WPF User Control Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to group some textboxes into usercontrols, but my observablecollection did not display to combobox, can anyone have a look?

What I am trying to do is to create a populated combobox, and bind the selectedvalue back to main window

```
public partial class uc1 : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item1> Item1s { get; set; }

    public string Display1 { get; set; }

    public Item1 Item
    {
        get { return (Item1)GetValue(ItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Item.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Item", typeof(Item1), typeof(uc1), new PropertyMetadata(default(Item1)));

    public uc1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
             Init Item1s
        }
    }
```

Here are the xaml

```
<UserControl x:Name="pp">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=pp}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox Height="25"
              Margin="5,0"
              DisplayMemberPath="Property1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Item1s}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Item}" />       

</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what isn't working?  Is the combobox completely empty?  Are you getting any errors in the Output console at runtime?  Consider running SnoopWPF and inspecting your binding at runtime to see what actually isn't working.

Comment: You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: @LordWilmore Checked with Snoop, the itemsources is empty, therefore the combobox is empty. and there are no error in output

Comment: @Lennart Isn't ObservableCollection implemented INotfiyPropertyChanged already?